# Is there a way to overcome lag between changes in OneNote client and API results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, onenote, superagent, onenote-api

Changes in OneNote client aren't immediately reflected in [apigee](https://apigee.com/onenote/embed/console/onenote/). For example:

- Renaming a section in OneNote client. Apigee shows the old name.
- Adding a section and adding notes to that section in OneNote; these
  aren't reflected in my app that uses the API. As seen below:

[image]

Is this a API call caching issue or a known OneNote issue?
Whats the recommended way to resolve it? 
I'm using [Superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) and wondering if its [no-cache plugin](https://github.com/johntron/superagent-no-cache) would resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the following header to an API request it seems to reduce the amount of caching that happens.

```
FavorDataRecency: true
```

The trade off seems to be a larger overhead for the request and a greater likelihood of triggering throttling (429 errors).
The OneNote team could probably explain this more precisely.

Comment: This option in the OneNote API is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks for the update Jorge,  
Will a request that includes this header fail or will it just be ignored?  
I have previously needed this header to prevent page requests from timing out, is this no longer the case?  
Cheers  
Steve

Comment: You should not see timeouts, do report them if you do. The header will just be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This option is no longer supported.

---

Codeye is right - You can use

```
FavorDataRecency: true
```

To skip our index. However, the index is refreshed based on changes made to OneNote content, so the delay (if you choose to not use FavorDataRecency) shouldn't be more than a few minutes

Comment: If the changes are never shown, please notify in twitter @OneNoteDev and we will look into it.

Comment: Thanks @jorge. I've provided users with [4 steps to get started](https://github.com/komplexb/notifyer-electron#get-started) with my app, hopefully by the time they get to #4, synching has taken place.