# OneNote API is not returning new pages (even via ms graph explorer)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I'm a creator of an app that integrates with OneNote API via Microsoft graph SDKs for Android/iOS. Several of my users reported that the new OneNote notes stopped syncing with the app (hundreds more affected by this).

I've been debugging this. And I can confirm that OneNote API does not return new pages.
To reproduce:

```
1) create some new notes

2) go to Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/)

3) user basic query (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages)
```

New pages are not being returned, even after a few days. My app uses the same endpoint to get the latest pages.

I would appreciate it if someone could look into this. I can provide all the data needed to debug.

Side Note: 
The official OneNote app sees the notes correctly (on both iOS and Android).

---

UPDATE

MS Graph Explorer started showing notes which were added 5 days ago (our users report the same). So it seems like a very long delay in propagating the data (the official OneNote app syncs new pages almost instantly). It would be great to get a response from OneNote team on this.

Looks like similar issue was reported 2 years ago

[Is there a way to overcome lag between changes in OneNote client and API results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172325/is-there-a-way-to-overcome-lag-between-changes-in-onenote-client-and-api-results)

Tested with "FavorDataRecency" header but still no results.

---

UPDATE 2 (05.02.2020)
The new notes stopped showing up completely (tested even after a few weeks time).
What is interesting is that if I create a new section the section pops up from the API endpoint immediately (just name, without notes).

Answer (score 1):

We believe this issue has been resolved. It was a bad machine cluster on our end that was causing the jobs to get stuck and hence the delay. Let us know. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Manjusha, thanks for following up on this. I have been testing this yesterday and today. Unfortunately, the issue is still there (on graph explorer and API). The last notes I can see are from 7 days ago.

Comment: would be great if you can follow up on this. The pages still don't show up.

Comment: UPDATE (06.02.2020) It looks like the OneNote team resolved the issue. The delay now is around 6-10 mins after you make an update or create a new note. Thank you!

Comment: UPDATE (17.03.2020) Unfortunately the same thing started happening again. No new pages are being returned. The last pages I can see come from 20.02.2020 @Manjusha

Comment: @Manjusha We can see this issue again, I'm not able to see the new notes returned from the MS Graph api response. We have many users impacted because of this on our end, would be grateful if you can give us an update on the fix asap.

Comment: @Manjusha I have the same issue too... The microsoft graph api for one note has stopped returning newly created pages since the past few weeks.

Comment: The problem is still there as of May 29 2020. This seems to be a caching problem or something related to syncing between the API gateway and the OneNote servers. I used webclipper to create pages and those can be seen for a while, some of them are later disappearing and the APIs are not reporting them as there. I have notebooks where I am seeing a few pagers created by the desktop client and then nothing in between these and the pages created in the same section via webclipper (some of these disappear later but if you put down the API link to the page you can still retrieve the content.